# ¿Cómo puedo reordenar registros de mi tabla en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla y quiero reordenar los registros de ella:

```
campo1 | campo2 | campo3
1        valor1   valor1
2        valor2   valor2
3        valor3   valor3
4        valor1   valor1
5        valor2   valor2
6        valor3   valor3
7        valor1   valor1
8        valor2   valor2
9        valor3   valor3
```

pero quiero reordenarlos y que mi tabla quede de la siguiente manera:

```
campo1 | campo2 | campo3
1        valor1   valor1
2        valor1   valor1
3        valor1   valor1
4        valor2   valor2
5        valor2   valor2
6        valor2   valor2
7        valor3   valor3
8        valor3   valor3
9        valor3   valor3
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. 
También, aprovecha y haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Comment: Campo 1 es una llave o es un campo? por que si no tendrias que hacerlo de otro modo o calcular el campo1 por que si es campo de tu tabla ya tiene ese valor si no es asi con un ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: ¿Cuando dices reordenar te refieres a mostrarla ordenada o a reescribirla (update) dando al id1 o campo1 valores distintos a los que tenia?

Answer (score 2):

El tema es generar una secuencia a partir del nuevo orden, en este caso `campo2, campo3`. En versiones de `mysql` anteriores a la 8, para generar un numerador debes trabajar con un variable que acumularás por fila. Algo como esto:

```
SELECT campo1,
       (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS nuevo_campo1,
       campo2,
       campo3
       FROM ejemplo e, 
       (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
       ORDER BY campo2, campo3;


| campo1 | nuevo_campo1 | campo2 | campo3 |
|--------|--------------|--------|--------|
|      1 |            1 | valor1 | valor1 |
|      4 |            2 | valor1 | valor1 |
|      7 |            3 | valor1 | valor1 |
|      2 |            4 | valor2 | valor2 |
|      5 |            5 | valor2 | valor2 |
|      8 |            6 | valor2 | valor2 |
|      3 |            7 | valor3 | valor3 |
|      6 |            8 | valor3 | valor3 |
|      9 |            9 | valor3 | valor3 |
```

A partir de `mysq v8` puedes usar directamente la función [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT campo1,
       row_number() over (order by campo2, campo3) AS nuevo_campo1,
       campo2,
       campo3
       FROM ejemplo e;
```

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera se ordenara tu tabla de manera alfabéticamente ascendente

```
SELECT * FROM TuTabla ORDER BY campo2, campo3 ASC
```

si lo quiere de manera alfabéticamente descendente

```
 SELECT * FROM TuTabla ORDER BY campo2, campo3 DESC
```

> Aclaro: la primera es opcional, con el "order by" y el nombre del campo, el motor asume orden ascendente. A su vez está se ordenará primero por el campo2 y luego dentro de ese parámetro por el campo3.

Comment: Pero el busca reordenar tanto campo 1 y campo 2

Comment: Soluciónado!!!!!